# Mongo count for each document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have a collection of elements which can have parent-child relation. It looks like this:

```json
    [
     {
       _id: 1,
       parent_id: null
       name: 'First element',
     },
     {
       _id: 2,
       parent_id: 1
       name: 'Second element',
     },
    ]
```

I want to calculate how many children each element have. I need to compare _id and parent_id of each document.

What I want to get:

```json
    [
     {
      _id: 1,
       parent_id: null
       name: 'First element',
       childrens: 1,
     }
    {
      _id: 2,
       parent_id: 1
       name: 'Second element',
       childrens: 0,
     }
    ]
```

How can I achieve that? I tried to look in documentation for aggregation and other stuff but still I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$graphLookup` to perform a recursive lookup.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "startWith": "$_id",
      "connectFromField": "_id",
      "connectToField": "parent_id",
      "as": "children"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "children": {
        $size: "$children"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eyXrgpUrONO) for your reference.

Comment: Functionally this looks like the right answer to me.  Important context to add is that this is going to process _all_ of the documents in the source collection. So a `$match` or similar should be prepended to scope the documents that are being processed. Otherwise this won't be scalable if it will be run against the entire collection